# Differenze tra "revisionare", "rivedere" e "controllare"

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, verbs, difference

Qualche giorno fa ho lasciato un messaggio nel [Bar Sport](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11367/bar-sport) in cui ho scritto "*revisare". Un giorno dopo, quando ho ricevuto una risposta da abarisone, l'ho riletto e mi sono accorta che "*revisare" non esiste in italiano. Ho voluto correggere il testo, ma ho avuto il dubbio se usare "revisionare", "rivedere" oppure "controllare". La mia domanda è: esistono differenze di uso o sfumature di significato tra i verbi "revisionare", "rivedere" e "controllare" quando vengono usati per indicare "fare una revisione"? Ho dato un'occhiata alle voci del vocabolario Treccani corrispondenti a questi verbi, ma non è stato di aiuto per chiarire il mio dubbio.

Comment: Mi piacerebbe sapere qual è la ragione del voto negativo. Ultimamente ho visto molti voti negativi dati alle domande di questo sito e, come ho già [espresso molte volte](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1337), penso sarebbe più costruttivo saperne la ragione.

Answer (score 3):

Il termine [revisionare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/revisionare/) viene più spesso utilizzato in relazione ad un veicolo o ad un impianto, anche se è, come dice Treccani, utilizzabile anche nei seguenti contesti:

> Sottoporre a revisione: *r. un compito, una prova d’esame; r. un’opera
>   letteraria; r. le bozze di stampa; r. un conto*, una pratica di
>   pensione;

e quindi anche al controllo di quanto scritto.

Per quanto riguarda il termine [rivedere](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rivedere/), l'accezione che si adatta maggiormente al contesto da te citato è la seguente:

> **b.** Controllare, esaminare con attenzione uno scritto per correggere,
>   modificare, riscontrare: *r. un discorso, una relazione, un contratto;
>   r. i conti*; con lo stesso uso e sign. di correggere: *r. i compiti
>   degli alunni; r. le bozze di stampa*. Com. l’espressione fig. *r. le
>   bucce a qualcuno*, sottoporre le sue azioni o i suoi lavori a un esame
>   e controllo rigoroso, pedante e minuto.

Inoltre nell'accezione **c.**, sempre su Treccani, si può notare che rivedere può avere anche il significato di revisionare.

> **c.** Di congegni, meccanismi, apparati e impianti, verificare
>   l’efficienza del funzionamento e lo stato di conservazione delle varie
>   parti, compiendo le eventuali riparazioni: ho fatto r. il motore, i
>   freni, l’impianto di riscaldamento (v. anche revisione e revisionare).

Per quanto riguarda il termine [controllare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/controllare/) (anche se per allinearsi agli altri due termini della tua domanda dovrebbe essere *ricontrollare*) ha sicuramente un utilizzo più generico:

> **1. a.** Verificare una cosa per accertarne la regolarità e l’esattezza: *c. un documento, una data, i biglietti, i bagagli; controlla l’ora sul
>   tuo orologio; controlla che la porta sia chiusa; hai controllato di
>   avere chiuso l’acqua?*;

Comment: Quindi, quando si tratta di un testo, di solito si usa "rivedere"?

Comment: Personalmente userei rivedere in luogo di revisionare, che lego maggiormente a qualcosa di fisico e concreto. È comunque accettabile l'utilizzo di revisionare riferito ad un testo.

Comment: E perché dovrebbe essere "ricontrollare"? Quando ho scritto il messaggio sulla stanza di chat (non so se si dica così), non penso che nessun utente della comunità abbia mai controllato quello che ho scritto sul post a cui mi riferivo. E perché gli altri hanno il prefisso "re-" o "ri-"?

Comment: Semplicemente perché revisionare significa visionare di nuovo e rivedere vedere di nuovo. Ricontrollare in questo caso significherebbe verificare di nuovo. Magari il refuso sul post è stato notato ma il significato era comunque tranquillamente comprensibile.

Comment: Quando parli di refuso, ti riferisci a scrivere "revisare" (che era quello che avevo scritto prima) o a scrivere "controllare"?

Comment: Al termine revisare.

Answer (score 3):

Qualche aggiunta alla ottima risposta di @abarisone.

Come ha già detto @abarisone, *revisionare*, *rivedere* e *(ri)controllare* sono tutti applicabili ad un testo.

Da un punto di vista del registro linguistico, *revisionare* suona molto formale e tecnico. Infatti si parla normalmente di *revisioni* di un testo per indicare le successive versioni durante un processo di creazione di un testo, magari in un contesto professionale. In altre parole, dalla bozza iniziale alla versione finale di un testo, ci possono essere diverse revisioni, e il verbo *revisionare* è facile che si usi in quei contesti.

I termini più comuni sono *rivedere* o *controllare*. Quale dei due, dipende molto dallo stile del parlante. Entrambi veicolano l'idea di "rileggere il testo per vedere se ci sono evidenti errori o per aggiustarne il significato". A seconda del contesto e del tono del discorso (soprattutto nel parlato), possono indicare sia un controllo meticoloso che un controllo veloce. Con opportuni avverbi possono esprimere tutta la gamma della "qualità" della revisione.

Esempi:

*Hai consegnato il tema alla professoressa? Non ancora, voglio ancora rivederlo/controllarlo.*

*Hai mandato le bozze del volantino in tipografia? No. Non ho ancora avuto il tempo di rivederle/controllarle.*

*Scusa se me ne vado così presto, ma stasera devo proprio rivedere un articolo prima di inviarlo al giornale.*

Non concordo pienamente con @abarisone sul fatto che *ricontrollare* sia sullo stesso piano di *rivedere*. Il prefisso "ri-" può esprimere sia la ripetizione (*ricontrollare* = *controllare nuovamente*) che un rafforzativo (*ricontrollare* = *controllare attentamente*).

Naturalmente si tratta di sfumature, ma in un contesto neutro "ricontrollare" dà l'idea di un controllo più minuzioso rispetto a "rivedere" o semplicemente "controllare".

Tuttavia tieni presente che è anche una questione di stile del parlante e del contesto: il "rivedere" di una persona minuziosa può essere più accurato del "ricontrollare" di una persona superficiale!

Comment: Ho come l'impressione che rivedere implichi almeno delle correzioni o comunque delle modifiche, mentre controllare implichi solamente la segnalazione degli errori o delle cose da modificare. Ti torna?

Comment: @Zachiel Sono termini dal significato molto sfumato. Al di là delle definizioni da dizionario, dipende assolutamente dal parlante e dal contesto (anche "microgeografico", cioè dalla specifica comunità di parlanti). Questo soprattutto nella lingua parlata. Ad esempio, le seguenti frasi sono possibili: "Ho rivisto gli appunti che mi hai lasciato sulla conferenza. Mi sembra che siano molto completi."; "Ho controllato le bozze del progetto e ho dovuto correggere un mucchio di imprecisioni!". Non ha senso cercare di rendere rigorosa la definizione, perché la gente li usa in entrambi i sensi.

Comment: @Zachiel Mi spiego meglio: "rivedere" può sia implicare una modifica del testo, che un controllo (più o meno approfondito) senza modifiche. Ad esempio, un ingegnere può "rivedere" una relazione stilata da un tecnico suo sottoposto e in seguito dire a quest'ultimo di fare delle modifiche. L'ingegnere non ha effettuato modifiche. D'altra parte un correttore di bozze di una casa editrice può "rivedere" il testo di un manoscritto di un autore e implicitamente modificarlo per correggere errori di ortografia o grammatica. Ribadisco: il contesto anche del singolo discorso è fondamentale.